# display selected item from listview

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to review the selected item from listview, provided that when filtering, the selected visible element is selected

This code works well if the item is selected without filtering.
If the filtering process is complete, it will display elements that are not visible in the same position

```
 private List<string> itemlist;

 listviewa.ItemClick += Listnames_ItemClick;
        private void Listnames_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
         
            string itemcheck = itemlist[e.Position].ToString();
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, itemcheck, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }


//filter
   void _SV_QueryTextChange(object sender, Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);
       
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the process

```
enter code here
```

private List itemlist;

listviewa.ItemClick += Listnames_ItemClick;
private void Listnames_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{

```
        string itemcheck = itemlist[e.Position].ToString();
        Toast.MakeText(Activity, itemcheck, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

//filter
void _SV_QueryTextChange(object sender, Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
{
_adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);

```
    }
```